# sonar c++ community plugin not finding all issues

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I am trying to run my project with the sonar C++ community plugin
To test it, I included a division by 0 but the plugin doesn't catch it

Here is the code :

```
int test() {
    int i = 0;
    int f = 10 / i;
}
```

This should show that the division by 0 is incorrect, but it does not identify this issue and shows other minor issues. I have seen in logs that this file is getting scanned.

**Is there anything I am missing?**

Comment: Static code analysis tools are prone to such errors (false negatives). Just choose a better one.

Comment: Does it find it if you just do `int f = 10 / 0`?

Comment: Is test being called anywhere in your software?

Comment: yes this is within the project and it is getting called as per the log that sonar is showing